# ThreeJS Flashing/Shooting Star

Tags: three.js, tween

I am looking at this link https://www.igoodi.eu/home and wondering how they are doing that "flashing" / "shooting" stars. Is it a sphere that's being scaled down/up or zoom in/out? But when I tried to do that the star is deformed with respect to x,y,z position. I want it to be perfect sphere shaped when it is scaled/zoomed up.

Comment: The linked page is most likely using [`Points`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points) for its star field. You can change the shape using textures (like [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_custom_attributes_points3)), or by creating a custom shader to draw the point as a circle.

Comment: Yea but what I was trying to figure out is how do they do the disappearing points.

Comment: If you look at the code for the example I linked, they scale the points up and down, which would create the same effect. if you scaled the point down to have a size of zero.

Comment: That seems good but how to do the jumping of x,y positions because in that example it just scale up in one position. I want to achieve that when it scales up/down it goes to a different x or y position back and forth.

Comment: Based on your example, I assumed you had a field of objects. Are you trying to do this with only one, or a limited set of objects? Because that changes things a bit.

Comment: I'd use `THREE.Points()` with `THREE.ShaderMaterial()` (flat circles of texture) instead of `THREE.SphereBufferGeometry()`/`THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry()` (spheres).

Comment: @TheJim01 Yes I have a field of objects. And what I have now is the scaling effect using shaders but I don't know how to do the shifting of position per object.